# c++11 -Template MetaProgramming - Error: template parameters not used in partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

i am getting stuck with a partial template implementation, the idea is to provide a class (a builder) that is select at compile time using an enum class definition, also i want to provide the name of file and a class name for manage from the factory singleton. But this is not compiling, i am trying several hours, but i cannot see what i am doing wrong. 
This is the code:

```
enum class BuildersType
{
   ComunicationBuilder
};

//class definition
template<BuildersType, class ... Args>
class BuiderType;

//class implementation
template<const char * const FILENAME , const char *  const CLASSNAME, class ClassToConfigurate>
class BuiderType<BuildersType::ComunicationBuilder,const char * const ,const char * const ,ClassToConfigurate>
{
   public:

};

template<const char * const FILENAME , const char * const CLASSNAME>
class AnotherBuilder
{
};

namespace Test
{
   static constexpr char FILENAME []="aFileName";
   static constexpr char  CLASSNAME []="ClassName";
   class TestClass{};
}

int main()
{

   BuiderType<BuildersType::ComunicationBuilder,Test::FILENAME,Test::CLASSNAME,Test::TestClass> aBuilder;
   AnotherBuilder<Test::FILENAME,Test::CLASSNAME> aAnotherBuilder;
   return 0;
}
```

The compile ouput :

```
Error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 class BuiderType<BuildersType::ComunicationBuilder,const char * const ,const char * const ,ClassToConfigurate>
       ^
main.cpp:14:7: error:         'FILENAME'
main.cpp:14:7: error:         'CLASSNAME'
```

At this hours i am really tired, and i am asking help. 
Thx in advance
//=====================================================
For simplicity I will post the code with the solution:

```
enum class BuildersType
{
  ComunicationBuilder
};

//class definition
//Add here definition here of the templates non type arguments
template<BuildersType, const char * const FILENAME , const char *  const CLASSNAME,class ... Args>
class BuiderType;

//class implementation

template<const char * const FILENAME , const char *  const CLASSNAME, class ClassToConfigurate, class ... Args>
class BuiderType<BuildersType::ComunicationBuilder,FILENAME , CLASSNAME ,ClassToConfigurate,Args...>
{
public:

};
template<const char * const FILENAME , const char * const CLASSNAME>
class AnotherBuilder
{

};
namespace Test
{
static constexpr char FILENAME []="aFileName";
static constexpr char  CLASSNAME []="ClassName";
    class TestClass{};
}
int main()
{

    BuiderType<BuildersType::ComunicationBuilder,Test::FILENAME,Test::CLASSNAME,Test::TestClass> aBuilder;
    AnotherBuilder<Test::FILENAME,Test::CLASSNAME> aAnotherBuilder;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class template `BuiderType` has a non type template parameter of type `BuildersType` and a pack of type template parameters named `Args` but your specialization has two non type template parameters `FILENAME` and `CLASSNAME` (where you use non of them to actually specialize `BuiderType`). In the line where you declare/define `aBuilder` you use a set of template parameters that is incompatible to the declaration of `template<BuildersType, class ... Args> class BuiderType;` because here you do not have any non type template parameters besides the first one.

This snippet has the same behaviour:

```
template<class ... Args> class A;

// this specialization has a template parameter that 
// 1. cannot and
// 2. will not be used in the parameter list for A
template<int I> class A<int> { };

int main()
{

  A<int> a; // error: A is an incomplete type
  A<2> b;   // error: '2' is not a type but 
            // A template expects type parameters

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pixelchemist Eh eh, sorry, it's my obsession :-P